# How to extract failure messages from databricks job runs?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am working on creating a dataframe which ultimately will feed into a tableau report. The data is supposed to be extracted from the databricks job run for failed jobs and along witht he reason of the failure. I was able to extract the failed jobs by using the /api/2.1/jobs/runs/get?run_id. But I am struggling with finding a way to extract the error messages from the notebook url (the api doesn't have)

for example : I need to read the below
AnalysisException:'and the message here'

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use different api in databricks and tried to read from notebook url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this api `/api/2.1/jobs/runs/get-output`.
This is the link to its documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/getrunoutput.
If the job has failed, there's going to be an `error` field in the API response.